# ZoomOut and ZoomIn Images in Windows Phone 7 using double tap

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I m doing ZoomOut of an image using the following code.

```
private void OnDoubleTap(object sender, Microsoft.Phone.Controls.GestureEventArgs e)
{
           scale.ScaleX += <some value>
           scale.ScaleY += <some value>
}
```

I want to achieve the following thing. When I double tap  for the first time on the image it should ZoomIn and when I double tap for the second time on the image it should come back to normal size. Any idea how to achieve it . Please let me know your suggestions.

Thanks,
Mugu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your OnDoubleTap works, and normal scale is 1.

```
private void OnDoubleTap(object sender, Microsoft.Phone.Controls.GestureEventArgs e)
{
 if(scale.ScaleX == 1 && scale.ScaleY == 1) //The scale is currently 1, enlarge
 {
   scale.ScaleX = 1.5;
   scale.ScaleY = 1.5;
 } else { //Its bigger, reset to 1.
   scale.ScaleX = 1;
   scale.ScaleY = 1;
 } 
}
```